# Re-structure array based on parent/child relationship

Tags: php, arrays, parent, relationship

I have the following array structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 83
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => Questionnaire one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 84
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => Questionnaire two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 85
            [parent_id] => 83
            [title] => Questionnaire three
        )

)
```

I want to re-structure the array so child items are listed under their parents. For example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 83
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => Questionnaire one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 85
            [parent_id] => 83
            [title] => Questionnaire three
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 84
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => Questionnaire two
        )
)
```

I've searched previous questions but found none of them actually achieve the above.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Is that comming from a database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
$array = Array(
        "0" => Array("id" => 83,"parent_id" => 0,"title" => "Questionnaire one"),
        "1" => Array("id" => 84,"parent_id" => 0,"title" => "Questionnaire two"),
        "2" => Array("id" => 85,"parent_id" => 83,"title" => "Questionnaire three"));

$id = array_map(function ($item) {return $item["id"];}, $array);
$parent = array_filter($array, function ($item){return $item['parent_id'] == 0;});
$lists = array();

foreach ($parent as $value)
{
    $lists[] = $value ;
    $children = array_filter($array, function ($item) use($value) {return $item['parent_id'] == $value['id'];});
    foreach($children as $kids)
    {
        $lists[]  = $kids ;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($lists);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 83
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => Questionnaire one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 85
            [parent_id] => 83
            [title] => Questionnaire three
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 84
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => Questionnaire two
        )

)
```

Comment: `multiGroup($array, "id", "parent_id")` prints out the same array structure as my original array.  I want the child items to be listed under their parents?  I also don't want to create a child item with a sub array like your second example.

Comment: Does this solution require any specific PHP version as I get this output:  `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 83
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => Questionnaire one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 84
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => Questionnaire two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 85
            [parent_id] => 83
            [title] => Questionnaire three
        )

)`  which is the same input. I'm running PHP 5.3.3.  I have a feeling use() is not running for me.

Comment: Nope it works fine with php 5.3 .. see http://codepad.viper-7.com/hirHId what version are you using ???

Comment: I'm running 5.3.3.  Strange as I have copied and pasted your code and my output is not correct.  Is the same solution possible without using use() function. For some reason this is not working for me?

Comment: Hold on then let me take a look at this again carefully

Comment: If I pass in child as 3rd param to multiGroup it works as expected.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/p16TvU  I cant vote up as i'm not allowed but I want to say thank you so much for your help and patience with me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [uksort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php). Heres a [DEMO](http://codepad.org/v1WBdlAe).

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  if ($stock[$a] != $stock[$b]) return $stock[$b] - $stock[$a];
  return strcmp($a, $b);
}

$a = array(5 => 'apple', 1 => 'banana', 6 => 'orange', 2 => 'kiwi');

uksort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
   echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: This does not achieve the re-structuring that I want.

Comment: What is `$stock`?