# Sort all child by parent id

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, relationship

i have array like this:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Bazowa
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Główna
            [parent_id] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => PlayStation
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => Xbox
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [name] => Nintendo
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [name] => PC
            [parent_id] => 2
        )
)
```

and i want sort this array like tree on screenshot below:
[Screen of tree what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D3Uk.png)

i trying use this [Sort array values based on parent/child relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121729/sort-array-values-based-on-parent-child-relationship/39392197)

```
        foreach($xml->children()->children() as $value) {
        if($value->active == 1) {
            $categories[] = [
                'id' => (int) $value->id,
                'name' => (string) $value->name->language,
                'parent_id' => (int) $value->id_parent
            ];
        }
    }
    $parent_ids = [];

    $parents = ['' => []];
    foreach($categories as $val) {
        $parents[$val['parent_id']][] = $val;
    }
    $sorted = $parents[''];
    dump($parents); exit;
    for($val = reset($sorted); $val; $val = next($sorted)) {
        if(isset($parents[$val[0]])) {
            foreach($parents[$val[0]] as $next) {
                $sorted[] = $next;
            }
        }
    }
```

The most important thing for me is that everything displays well in select, which is something like this:

-Playstation 
-- Playstation 5 
--- Gry 
--Playstation 3
--- Gry 
Anyone can help me?

EDIT:
Problem solved by [Build a tree from a flat array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840319/build-a-tree-from-a-flat-array-in-php)

Comment: What did you try? The simplest solution is creating a category tree in form of multilevel array. for sorting by value of subarray you should use [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), however using "I want to" + screenshot doesn't describe your problem good enough. Also even if using screenshot include it here and display it inline instead of linking to the third part service.

Comment: @biesior ok, sorry, I corrected the post, hope you can understand it better now

Comment: You have relations here between parent-child elements, so you need to create a nested array representing the tree, you can do it using PHP or JS, depends on your needs. If I understood properly, while it works in another part of the code (for the select) you can check how it's done there and copy the solution.

Comment: I don't quite understand how I could do this

Comment: creating trees is much easier using recursive to fetch data from data base, can you access it like that or you have only this array?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
 return $a["parent_id"] > $b["parent_id"];
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work the way it wants to. This way I only sort by parent ID, and I want it to go in the appropriate tree that I indicated in the example.